# how add whitespace in string for searching menu?

Tags: mysql, regex, search, whitespace

I try build menu searching in website. Example I have data string is "Volvo XC60 B3D" or "HP Lion D19" in database, and I try input in searching menu is "VolvoXc60B3D" or "HPLionD19" and the result found is 0, I already try using `%Like%` OR `Full-Text` but still not working, i think use `trim`

```
UPDATE item SET 
name = LTRIM(RTRIM(name)), 
description = LTRIM(RTRIM(description))
```

for all data in database but not sure that is good solution because sometimes the item name uses - or / like "Dell-Xps", any one can give me solution please???

EDIT 1
Sorry, not using update, I tried to eliminate the spaces in the data ( 'name' ) then choose the data sought by the user ( already removed spaces ) using like / full -text.

Comment: Trim removes leading and trailing spaces, so trim will not help.

Comment: @Tushar: Note: Trim removes them only from the start and end of the string

Comment: @Cerbrus Already corrected, `leading and trailing` spaces

Comment: replace the all the chars in search term with `letter.*`, so `AIM` should appear as `A.*I.*M`. Now pass this as regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That would match: _"Ailment"_, when you really want _"Aim"_

Comment: or replace boundary exists before capital letters with `space`, ie `foA` should return `fo A`. For this case I sgould use `([^A-Z])([A-Z])`, `\1 \2`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: _"VolvoXC60B3D"_ -> _"Volvo X C60 B3 D"_ That won't work. The OP just needs to remove spaces from the text he's searching in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some query i got it

```
select REPLACE (name," ","") AS 'FIND' 
from item 
WHERE REPLACE (name," ","") LIKE '%VolvoXc60B3D%'
```

Thank you for try helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `replace`:

```
UPDATE item SET 
name = REPLACE(name, ' ',''), 
description = REPLACE(description, ' ','')
```

If you don't want to UPDATE you can leave your field as is an use replace in the search query:

```
SELECT name, description 
FROM YourTable
WHERE REPLACE(name, ' ','') = 'VolvoXc60B3D' 
    AND REPLACE(description, ' ','') = 'YourDescriptionWithoutSpaces'
```

Comment: thank you for reply, well that a good idea but item from supplier always increases, so not sure update is good solution.

Comment: @Vilthering I only modifyed you code: you used `UPDATE`. Anyway I updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I try follow your coding and got error, i try this "SELECT name, description 
FROM item
WHERE REPLACE(name, ' ','')
    AND REPLACE(description, ' ','');

Comment: @Vilthering What error do you get? Pay attention: you need to put `REPLACE(name, ' ','') = 'something'`

Comment: whether it is possible if we have a lot of data? i mean must replace 1 by 1?, i try select REPLACE (name," ","") as NAME from item, but i don't know how mix with like or full-text

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need. If you need to update all your data into the DB you can use the UPDATE query. If you don't want to modify your data into database you can leave them as are and use the SELECT query each time you need to extract data filling the WHERE conditions according to what you need to extract

Comment: sorry if you not understand what i mean, i try not modify database, and try to eliminate the spaces in the database and then select the data based(after eliminate the spaces) on the user data sought.(while user using search)

Comment: @Vilthering **i try not modify database, and try to eliminate the spaces in the database** Sorry but this don't make sense for me

Comment: The standard approach to name problems is to modify the data into a canonical form _before_ inserting it into the database.  This implies Perl scripts (or whatever) to modify the text, squeezing out (or adding in) spaces, slashes, dashes, etc., and removing unwanted phrases.  After that, the "search" become easy.